# Relative Solubilities of Salts in Acidic Solution

Tags: solubility

I stumbled across this problem which I don't understand the answer to:

Which solid is much more soluble in 1 M $\ce{HCl}$ than in $\ce{H2O}$?

(A) $\ce{CaHPO_4}$

(B) $\ce{CaCl_2}$

(C) $\ce{BaBr2}$

(D) $\ce{BaSO4}$

Comment: Surely that must be (A). $\ce{HCl}$ would turn it into the more soluble $\ce{Ca(H2PO4)2}$.

Comment: How is that more soluble than CaHPO4?

Comment: It's an experimental fact. You want to know how can we predict it just by looking at the formula? That can't be done reliably.

Comment: @IvanNeretin why not H3PO4 ? why would it stop at CaHPO4?

Comment: Check the answer in the back. But I would say (A), because hydrogen phosphate is the strongest base out of the other anions. If it is a strong base, that means that it is much favored to form dihydrogen phosphate, which shifts the equilibrium further to the right.

Comment: I did, but I don't understand why (A) is the answer.

Comment: @DavePhD You are right, the acid would drive it all the way to $\ce{CaCl2}$. Thus it would suffice to know just two facts: good solubility of $\ce{CaCl2}$ and not-so-good of $\ce{CaHPO4}$. Can these be explained in a rigorous way, without memorization? I don't think so.

Comment: @IvanNeretin so you disagree with my answer?

Comment: @DavePhD No, I agree quite completely, but your answer is still based upon the fact (known to any chemist, of course) that $\ce{CaHPO4}$ is poorly soluble, while $\ce{CaCl2}$ is well soluble. How did you know that?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I agree, you would need to know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, an example: Magnesium hydroxide, $\ce{Mg(OH)_2}$, is much more soluble in acid than pure water. This is because when it dissolves in pure water, $\ce{Mg(OH)_2 (s)<-> Mg^{2+} (aq) + 2OH^- (aq)}$, with only a little bit of the aqeuous products. ($\ce{Mg(OH)_2}$ is "insoluble".) However, if there is quite a bit of $\ce{H^+}$, then the $\ce{OH^-}$, which is a strong base, will react with $\ce{H^+}$ and form something else (in this case $\ce{H_2O}$). This is akin to taking out some $\ce{OH^-}$, and by Le-Chatelier's principle, will shift the equilibrium right, and you can dissolve more $\ce{Mg(OH)_2}$ in.

In your problem, $\ce{Cl^-}$ and $\ce{Br^-}$ are both exceedingly weak bases, so they don't react with $\ce{H^+}$ to form something else. (HCl and HBr are strong acids). Next, I know that $\ce{SO_4^{2-}}$ is a noticeable base (it will form $\ce{HSO_4^{-}}$, not a strong acid), and so is $\ce{HPO_4^{2-}}$ (will form $\ce{H_2PO_4^{-}}$, not a strong acid), so they are two potential options. Now we just need to figure out which base is stronger than the other, or which conjugate acid is weaker than the other. There is prior knowledge involved now: because $\ce{HSO_4^{-}}$ is a stronger acid than $\ce{HPO_4^{2-}}$, then the base of $\ce{H_2PO_4^{-}}$, which is $\ce{HPO_4^{-}}$, is the stronger base than $\ce{SO_4^{2-}}$, (and consequently all of the other ones). The ionic compound containing the stronger base is more soluble in acidic solution, and vice versa for basic solution. So (A)

Answer (score 0):

Chloride, Bromide, and Sulfate all correspond to strong acids, while phosphate corresponds to a weak acid.

With 1M H+ available, phosphate will be essentially fully protonated, while the others will still be anions.